# How would I sort and array by its values in php

Tags: php, sorting, csv, foreach

I have this array called $csv, it contains cars that have year, make and model.

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'csv/file.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
array_shift($csv); 

foreach($csv as $car){

$year = $car[3];
$make = $car[4];
$model = $car[5];

echo $year;
}
```

This gives me - 
2011
2009
2012
2012
2013

How would I filter the results to display in order by newest to oldest?

Comment: didn't you post something related earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108849/how-do-i-sort-and-organize-data-from-csv-file-in-php

Comment: Earlier I wanted to get the count for inventory based on how long I have had each car. This is for displaying the inventory itself in a feed. It displays now but I want to know how to filter the results.

Comment: Have a look at the many sorting functions that PHP has to offer http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: then these Q&A's http://stackoverflow.com/q/1272494/ - http://stackoverflow.com/q/11649840/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Sort Array by date value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557373/php-sort-array-by-date-value)

Comment: or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649840/multidimensional-array-sorting-procedure-for-csv-files?lq=1) one for multidimensional arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$years = [];
foreach($csv as $car){
    $years[] = $car[3];
}

rsort($years);

foreach($years as $year) {
    echo $year;
}
```

If you need low-to-high sorting use sort instead of rsort.

Comment: Perfect thank you just the answer I was looking for!

Comment: how would I add other values from the same column as the year like "make" ?

Comment: do you want to keep them sorted by year too?

If so you have a few options:
1. create an array with year as keys, and other data on values and sort on the keys.
2. (Best IMO). Simply create a sort function. If you don't care about the original array $csv, you could directly sort that based on the third column.  Take a look at this - http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php